# How to send specific answer to client from trigger (mssql)

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing client-server application, where server is MS SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to realize opportunity to set rules to start some functions on client side when added/edited data satisfies specific conditions. I want to do this from tables' triggers, where I'm going to send message to client to start function.

1. I didn't find opportunity to send TCP packet from triggers. I think that using CLR would be good for this?
2. Is there any better approaches?

Comment: look into service broker for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't need to create an other connection. There are some message queuing function in sql-server, which can used.

You can also check if Extended Events meet your requirements.
[Introducing SQL Server Extended Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

What kind of clients/language/db-connection are you using?